# WebSQL: jQuery for each error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, web-sql

I am trying [WebSQL example](http://luthfihariz.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/android-sqlite-phonegap-jquerymobile/) in Google Chrome.

There is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

//add listener when device ready
var db = window.openDatabase("Dummy_DB", "1.0", "Just a Dummy DB", 200000); //will create database Dummy_DB or open it

//function will be called when device ready
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

//create table and insert some record
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerPlayer (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Club TEXT NOT NULL)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Alexandre Pato", "AC Milan")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Van Persie", "Arsenal")');
}

//function will be called when an error occurred
function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

//function will be called when process succeed
function successCB() {
    console.log("success!");
    db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
}

//select all from SoccerPlayer
function queryDB(tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SoccerPlayer',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx,result){

    var len = result.rows.length, i;
    console.log("LEN=" + len)
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          console.log(result.rows.item(i));  // print ok:  Object {id: 1, Name: "Alexandre Pato", Club: "AC Milan"} test.html:47 ....
      }

    $('#SoccerPlayerList').empty();
    $.each(result.rows,function(index){
        var row = result.rows.item(index); // Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'item' on 'SQLResultSetRowList': The index provided is not a number. test.html:52(anonymous function) test.html:52st.extend.each jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1querySuccess test.html:51
        // var row = result.rows.item(1); // it works good
        $('#SoccerPlayerList').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['Name']+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">Club '+row['Club']+'</p></a></li>');
    });

    $('#SoccerPlayerList').listview();
}

});


</script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Soccer Player</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
     <ul id="SoccerPlayerList">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end of Soccer Player Page--->
</body>
</html>
```

If I use `var row = result.rows.item(index);` I get en error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'item' on 'SQLResultSetRowList': The index provided is not a number.`

But if I use number directly: `var row = result.rows.item(1)` output is good (JS add `<li>`).

Pure JavaScript for loop print all objects to console. So WebSQL usage is probably good.

Where is an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
for(index=0;index<results.rows.length;index++)
{

     result.rows.item(index);
     ..........................

}
```